# Can't login to Tuleap using default admin and password

Tags: login, tuleap

When I login using the default admin and the password, it always shows:

> "Invalid Password Or User Name".

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing that "default password" in Tuleap. The administrator password is generated automatically and randomly during install. You can find it (and other generated passwords) in `/root/.tuleap_passwd`